Sample raster (Landsat) using points (preferably using Python or maybe GEE Code editor)
I have a point shapefiles that covers an area of Multiple states and multiple Landsat (NDVI) tiles from a span of May-Sept for 2005, 2010, 2015, 2016, and 2021. Let's just focus on 2005 for now. I would like to sample NDVI (from which I calculated already and exported as tiles) for each point for each month (or preferably each two weeks) from the data. My data is organized in directories of Year then the Landsat used (for now can focus on Landsat 5). I need to somehow find the values over the period (either month or 2 week intervals) and assign a date too that value (e.g. [Point Index][Some other columns containing important data][Geometry][Date Interval (could be two columns Start Date, End Date)][NDVI].
def sample_NDVI_raster(NDVI_tile, wetland):

    with rasterio.open(NDVI_tile) as NDVI_Rast:
        
        wetland['NDVI_S2'] = wetland['NDVI']
        
        wetland_proj = wetland.to_crs(NDVI_Rast.crs)
        
        coords = [(geom.x, geom.y) for geom in wetland_proj.geometry]
        
        wetland['NDVI_S3'] = [x for x in NDVI_Rast.sample(coords)]
        
        wetland['NDVI'] = (wetland['NDVI_S2'] + wetland['NDVI_S3']) / 2
        
        wetland['NDVI'] = wetland['NDVI'].combine_first(wetland['NDVI_S2']).combine_first(wetland['NDVI_S3'])
        
        return wetland





files = r'D:\Landsat_NDVI\2005\Landsat_5_2005_NDVI'

wetland = r'D:\Extracted_PPR_Poly\PPR_Sinks_Cen\PPR_Sinks_Cen_2005\PPR_Sinks_Cen_2005.shp'

wetland = gpd.read_file(wetland)

wetland['NDVI'] = np.nan

wetland['NDVI_S3'] = np.nan


for file in os.listdir(files):
    
    if file.endswith('.tif'):
        NDVI_tile = os.path.join(files, file)
        
        sample_NDVI_raster(NDVI_tile, wetland)
        

            
            

This was some code I wrote just to see what would happen, it did not work when I ran it the NDVI value for every row would be the same and was something like -2.13e9. Even if it did work this would give me the average for the whole May-Sep period when I would rather break it down into month or 2 week intervals.
Perhaps I should write code that organizes my directory into directories of 2 week intervals? This is what my Landsat NDVI files look like  Or perhaps it would be easier to attempt to download the Landsat imagery already mosaic in GEE by two week intervals then perform the raster Extraction?

@Bera Another identifier for the tile

You can simplify the value extraction by using rasterstats:
import geopandas as gpd
from rasterstats import zonal_stats

df = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/pointgrid.shp")
raster_file = r"/home/bera/Drives/data1/gisdata/Sentinel2/2020/S2A_MSIL2A_20200809T102031_N0214_R065_T33VVD_20200809T130506.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T33VVD_A026803_20200809T102029/IMG_DATA/R10m/T33VVD_20200809T102031_B04_10m.jp2"

stats = zonal_stats(vectors=df.geometry, raster=raster_file, stats="max", nodata=0)

print(stats) #stats is a list of dictionaries:
#[{'max': 0.0}, {'max': 328.0}, {'max': 588.0}, {'max': 302.0}, {'max': 373.0}, {'max': 565.0}, {'max': 437.0}, {'max': 424.0}, {'max': 610.0}, {'max': 776.0}, {'max': 463.0}, {'max': 425.0}, {'max': 343.0}, {'max': 502.0}, {'max': 505.0}, {'max': 479.0}, 
# {'max': 450.0}, {'max': 230.0}, {'max': 196.0}, {'max': 194.0},...]

stats = [x["max"] for x in stats]
#print(stats)
#[0.0, 328.0, 588.0, 302.0, 373.0, 565.0, 437.0, 424.0, 610.0, 776.0, 463.0, 425.0, 343.0, 502.0, 505.0, 479.0, 450.0, 230.0, 196.0, 194.0, ...]

df["rasterval"] = stats

